# Github UI shows failing red X when Jenkins skips a build

Tags: jenkins, github, continuous-integration

I have a Jenkinsfile that contains a few logical checks for a commit to Github, and only after certain criteria are met, will it trigger a downstream build job. The relevant parts of the Jenkinsfile are below:

```
script {
            if (... a bunch of conditions) {
                echo 'Building because of on-demand job!'
                build job: '/my/downstream/job', parameters: [gitParameter(name: 'BRANCH', value: env.BRANCH_NAME),
                               gitParameter(name: 'GIT_BRANCH', value: env.GIT_LOCAL_BRANCH)], wait: true, propagate: true
            }

            echo 'Skipping'
            currentBuild.result = 'NOT_BUILT'
        }
```

However, in my Github UI, anytime a job is skipped, it is rendered as a failure. For instance, when a commit is made that does not satisfy the condition, Jenkins correctly skips the build:
[image]
However, on the Github commit history, it shows as a failure:
[image]

I know this is somewhat trivial and literally only for appearances but it is quite aggravating to see so many red Xs. Is the best solution just to switch the `currentBuild.result` to `SUCCESS`? I am somewhat hesitant to do so since it's not technically a success (nothing was built) but I don't see another way of getting Github to not mark it as failed.

Comment: Any success here? Seeing same thing these days... GitHub says the build is `Skipped` so they are definitely aware of `NOT_BUILT` Jenkins status. This is an issue for monorepos and automatic merge rules :(